# How to read a sub-array from a Json object in Datatables

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have been stuck with this issue for a long time now..:(

I have an object that im trying to read the sub-array from. below is the look of the JSON format. im trying to extract the `qaccess` values from it, as like `qaccess.0.product`, `qaccess.1.product`.

```
  "qaccess": [
    {
      "product": "wm.od.prod.nsr",
      "status": "enabled",
      "roleIdentifiers": [

      ],
      "permissionIdentifiers": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "product": "gp.od.dev.nsr",
      "status": "Active",
      "roleIdentifiers": [

      ],
      "permissionIdentifiers": [

      ]
    }
  ]
```

And below if what my code looks like:

```
addColumn: function(oObj, type, val){
    //however i checked now, and found that the `oObj, type, val` returns 'null' and hence i am unable to use the addColumn function anymore. that is one problem i faced and hence took up another approach of adding the function in the `mDataProp`, like the one shown in the EDIT part.

        propertySize = oObj.qaccess.length;

        for(i=0; i<propertySize; i=i+1){
        { 
        "mDataProp": "qaccess." + i + ".product",


            "sTitle": "Status",
            "sClass": "_status",
            "sWidth": "10%",
           }
        }


        });
})
        this.columns.push(col);
        // return the index of the new column
        return this.columns;


    },
```

To get multiple values of the object, can i  write it in for loop as shown above?
Ex:

`for(i=0; i<propertySize; i=i+1){
            { 
            "mDataProp": "qaccess." + i + ".product"}}`.

EDIT:

I also tried doing something like this :

```
columns: [
 {"mRender": function(obj, val, data){

    propertySize =  data.qaccess.length;
           for(i=0; i<propertySize; i=i+1){
            col= {
                "mDataProp": "qaccess." + i + ".product",
                sTitle: "Account Name", sClass: "_accountName", sWidth: "25%"
            }
        }       
  }
 }]
```

The `data` above returns: out of which im trying to get the value of 'qaccess[0].product' and 'qaccess[1].product' in my table.

```
.   qaccess: Array[2]
.    0: Object
.       permissionIdentifiers: Array[0]
.       product: "wm.od.prod.nsr"
.       roleIdentifiers: Array[0]
.       status: "enabled"
.   1: Object
⁃       permissionIdentifiers: Array[0]
⁃       product: "gp.od.dev.nsr"
⁃       roleIdentifiers: Array[0]
⁃       status: "Active"
```

how can i achieve the values of the `qaccess` array values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a JSFiddle with an example of how to access the data: http://jsfiddle.net/a3cc8vat/

Bottom line is that you use

```
obj.qaccess[1].product
```

Incorrect:

```
obj.qaccess.1.product
```

And you should not use quotes around the name. You for loop should be more like

```
for(i=0; i<propertySize; i=i+1){
        { 
        "mDataProp": this.qaccess[i].product,
```

Not sure if the `this` is needed for your example because it's hard to tell what the context is based on your code snippet.

Comment: thanks, for providing this idea. however, it works only when i have a single Object. when there are multiple Objects, it provides only the last object.qaccess details.any clue on how to handle multiple objects??? Thanks

Comment: Also the 'this.columns.push(col);' keeps adding columns to the table, if not refreshed. Is there any way i can avoid that?? Thnks

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you want?? Also you have referred to `this.columns` but columns is not in your code sample.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can answer your question if I can just get more details of what you are really needing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value using the code below:

`"mDataProp": oObj["qaccess"][i]["product"]`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
                mData: null,
                sTitle: "Products",
                sWidth: "10%",
                sClass: "_status",
                mRender: function (data, type, obj) {
                    var returnVal = "";
                  _.each(obj.qaccess, function(item, index){
                    returnVal += "<span class='_status'>" + item["product"] + "</span>";
                  });
                  return returnVal;

                }
```

This returned me: val1 val2.

Thanks @jwatts1980 for the help, however i need a to add commas between these two values.
some columns may have more than one values, if so i need to add comma so that its:

val1,val2.

Any help???